# Does Mutt require a password to open mail stored in Maildir format?

Tags: linux, email, password, mutt

I am a server administrator and want to be able to read emails (stored by EXIM in the "Maildir" format) in various accounts in a convenient, email client manner, without needing to enter a password.  This would be done from a root command line.  From what I have seen, "Mutt" will be able to access the various emails stored in the Maildir format, but I am unsure if I will need a password for each email account.  I do not want to install Mutt on the server only to find out I will need the password for each account.

Since I did not get any prompt responses, I went ahead and installed Mutt on my server.  Indeed, as root I can access all the various mail accounts on the server without needing any passwords.  Since most published information about Mutt addresses single, non root account access, they show a password being needed.  In my circumstances, a password is not required.  This allows me to assist my clients, and perform various email account housecleaning tasks easier than other ways which do not have any GUI.

Comment: where are these emails? on the local filesystem? elsewhere via some protocol?

Comment: The emails are on the local server saved in the maildir structure, the same server I would be using to run "mutt" from.  An alternative program generally avaiable to be run from the command line would also meet my requirements.

Comment: Rewritten to be clearer and more complete.

Comment: Please re-open this question.  I have tried to fully explain the issue I am trying to get answered.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't see why you should need account id or password, wenn the maildir is already provided by an external program. The integration of local maildirs in mutt is well documented.